# UK visa refusal For PLAB 2

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I had applied for a visit visa (business) to appear for my PLAB 2 exam on 21 June 2019. I had to attend practice classes from an academy in Manchester for which I had attached the invitation letter; my duration was 15 days to prepare my exam in a better way. I had mentioned the cost of my trip to be £1500 and my brother sponsoring me for £3000 (my entire trip).

1. My rejection letter stated that I was going with my mother, when I had nowhere in my form or cover letter mentioned that I am going with my mother, because I was going alone.
2. I had shown that my brother is my financial sponsor as I didnt have enough funds in my account. I had attested all the documents of my brother but somewhere in my form I made a mistake where I wrote the total money I have is £3000, but I had only £1200 in my account. I thought we had to write the total amount, so I put my brother's sponsor money, which was supposed to be £3000; he hadn't transferred it into my account, it was in his account only.
3. I made one more mistake in the form where they asked how much is the
   cost of travel to you personally. I wrote £1500 but I think I had to
   write nil there.

I don't know how to proceed now. Should I transfer £3000 into my account from my brother's account and get a bank statement proving the source of income? I don't have enough money in my account despite bring employed since Nov 2018 with a salary of £700 per month, as I had to make some big transactions such as booking my PLAB 2 exam (£830£), etc.

I have already booked the exam for £830 and I don't have much time left.

[image: '']
[image: '']

Comment: How to improve my next application?as i am intending to reapply within a week

Comment: @NumaanMuneer Read the answer linked above. If you have specific questions you can ask again. Also, of course, make sure you give the correct figures on your application. The mistake on your application is itself enough to cause a refusal.

Comment: The numbers in your documents did not match the numbers you wrote in the visa application. It appears you are already aware of this. You may reapply again and supply the correct information this time, and any additional documents that might be necessary.

Comment: @ Michael Hampton Shall i transfer the money from my brother’s bank account into my account and provide a proof for that?

Comment: Don't transfer the money; supply proof that your brother has the money and that he has it legitimately (i.e., his bank statements). See the answers [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/62411/11491).