# Retired Parents - Apply Visitor Visa

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

my husband is currently on ICT tier 2 and I will be joining him shortly. I would like my parents to accompany me when I travel to the UK. Hence I would like to apply visitor visa for them

A little background, my dad is a retired business man and his income comes from the following:
1. Interest from fixed deposits - ~12 lacs
2. Rent from an apartment - 20k per month
3. My sister helps them - 12.5k per month

Other than the above, my parents own 2 flats in Bangalore both put together worth 1cr. My question here is what all documents do they need to show while applying for a visitor visa?

Comment: Everything you need to know is on [gov.uk](http://gov.uk). You'll find a page on required documents [here](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) including a link to a PDF file detailing documents you might be asked to provide.

Comment: Be aware that _lakh_ and _crore_ are not widely understood outside south Asia. You might wish to write numbers in the Western style when communicating with people outside this region of the world.

Comment: Make sure you spend some time reading this site so you don’t fall into the traps of funds parking, provenance of funds, etc. you can use the search function to search those key words. Many applicants fall afoul of those traps.

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need to know is on [www.gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/). You'll find a page on required documents [here](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide) including a link to the [Guide to Supporting Documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) detailing documents you might be asked to provide.

Gov.uk says

> You’ll need to provide the following:
>
> - the dates you’re planning to travel to the UK
> - details of where you’ll be staying during your visit
> - how much you think your trip will cost
> - your current home address and how long you’ve lived there
> - your parents’ names and dates of birth
> - how much you earn in a year
>
> You might also need:
>
> - details of your travel history for the past 10 years (as shown in your passport)
> - your employer’s address and telephone number
> - your partner’s name, date of birth, and passport number
> - the name and address of anyone paying for your trip
> - the name, address and passport number of any family members you have in the UK
> - details of any criminal, civil or immigration offences you have committed

There are many other documents you may need to provide, all listed in the Guide. The Guide is long, and covers many requirements that may not apply to you, so I won't reproduce it here.

Be sure also to read some of the questions and answers on this site to help avoid the common pitfalls: [bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105), [Refusal on V 4.2](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) and [Funds Parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications) would be a good start.