# Can a relative sponsor my trip to uk instead of my parents?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, albanian-citizens

I am 17 years old and I'm from Albania. I want to go to England to meet my cousin but I have to apply for UK visa. The problem is that my parents' bank statements are not enough and my cousin doesn't have that much money in her account. My aunt told me that she wants to sponsor my trip but can she? Can I apply for visa and say that my aunt is going to pay for my trip?

Comment: The UK will want to know if you are really a tourist and plan to go back again. Part of that will be your economic situation, part will be who pays for the trip and why. If your aunt can afford to give you the money as a *gift*, that will explain where the money comes from. But it is not just about money in the bank account, it is about income and expenditure.

Comment: What if she gifts me through bank the money and i open a new account is it possible. Because i go to school here and i have no intentions of staying in uk for more than 2 weeks.

Comment: You would still have to explain where the money comes from. Sudden, unexplained deposits are very bad for your application.

Comment: @Ersiana That’s not usually a good idea - see this question on ‘funds parking’ https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications You’d still need to explain and document where the money came from. If the purpose of the trip is to meet your cousin, they could travel to Albania instead?

Comment: Do you have any suggestions what i can do in this situation. I have cash moneys but i was told that i cant use them. Thats why i dont know what to do

Answer (score 1):

UK Immigration Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules state that:

V 4.3 A visitor’s travel, maintenance and accommodation may be provided by a third party where the decision maker is satisfied that they:

(a) have a genuine professional or personal relationship with the visitor; and

(b) are not, or will not be, in breach of UK immigration laws at the time of decision or the visitor’s entry to the UK; and

(c) can and will provide support to the visitor for the intended duration of their stay.

So yes, you can state in your application that your aunt will pay the costs of your trip. She will need to provide you with documents to prove she can fulfil the commitment eg bank statements for the last 6 months, her employment contract (if she is employed). You will also need to prove the relationship between you.

You should be aware that needing a sponsor weakens your application. If you haven’t already done so, it may help you to read [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)