# UK Visa Refusal-Right to appeal-Glaring mistakes by the Visa Officer

Tags: visas, uk

A friend of mine applied for UK Visa and it was refused.
On examining the reasons for refusal it is clear that the Visa Officer has made mistakes.
For instance, at one Paragraph the visa officer admits that the monthly salary is Rs 80,000.00, and on the next paragraph he says the expected expenditure for the travel Rs 300,000.00 is 3 times of the applicant's annual salary!
Isnt my friend entitled to a re consideration of the decision as this is a glaring mistake?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What did the application say?  You won't get a decent answer without a scan of the refusal document (with personal information blanked out) being added to the question so we can get an idea of what the immigration official actually said in their own words.  And no, a UK visitor visa application has no right of appeal (although some people have had success with lodging a complaint and having their application reexamined, but its far from a guaranteed process).

Comment: In general, the approach recommended for this sort of thing is to apply again, with a cover letter detailing the discrepancies in the earlier decision (dont rant, dont be aggressive, dont demand, just point out the factual errors).  Be sure to include the previous denial in the relevant section of your new application, and you are also given an opportunity to include some detail there.

Comment: Sounds like there is a digit error somewhere.  Note that 8,000 * 12 = 96,000, making the 300,000 3x it.

Comment: See also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105

Comment: Despite the majority of what you are being told here, you can ask for reconsideration. You can do this by email or by post.

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in [**@the other one**'s answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/149279/46052), the 5th bullet raises concerns about **fund parking**:

> "I note this bank accounts *[sic]* balance was inflated by a total *[sic]* several large cash deposits that do not reconcile with your monthly income and that you have not provided any information surrounding the source of these funds."

**This may be the most serious objection in the refusal** and the most difficult to resolve since they now have the impression that you attempted to **deceive** them.

These answers explain the problem in detail:

- [What Is the Purpose of Bank Statements?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/95267)
- [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/92122/95267)

Answer (score 17):

**No, there's no right to appeal.** There's however nothing stopping you from submitting a fresh application. Point out and explain the mistakes and take care to make everything super clear to prevent further confusion.

That said, it looks like the mistake is a simple typo that has no real bearing on the decision. Even if the decision letter said "monthly" instead of "annual", the decision would still be entirely reasonable. Spending almost four months worth of salary on a 11-day visit to a friend is really, **really** hard to justify.

So think thrice before submitting a new application, because it seems doomed from the start.

Answer (score 11):

I am not seeing a mistake here at a glance. It wasn't until someone pointed it out that I noticed the annual/monthly mixup, but given the numbers it seems a clear typo.

It needs pointing out that though most visa refusal threads you find on this site involve people who are lying and attempting to cheat their way to a visa, you can still be refused a visa even if you're totally honest and open. This is the reason many find the need to lie.

This sort of refusal is nothing to worry about. You can still reapply on good terms when your situation improves. It's not at all the same as a refusal for breaking the rules.

In this case the refusal was because the friend is earning under £400 a month and says they will spend just under £1300 on a holiday. This is not normal behaviour, especially if its just to visit a friend they've only known three years. Thats the kind of massive spending you'd make for a dream once in a life time trip or to visit your mother on her deathbed, not a casual holiday.

Additionally I note an unhighlighted paragraph mentions sudden deposits to the account having taken place. This is a big no-no. It's a common way people try to trick the system; friends give them large sums of money, they get the visa due to proving they are rich, then they give their friends the money back.

Comment: There's a clear mistake: they mistook the applicant's monthly salary (£382) for his annual salary (which is actually £4,584), and thus believe his travel costs are triple his annual salary when they are less than a third.

Point taken that this is an unusually high expenditure to visit a friend.

Comment: IMO the only "mistake" is the typo of "annual" for "monthly". The numbers don't add up either way, and there the other objections are about the lack of supporting evidence. Somebody might plausibly spend 3 *months* salary on a round-the-world cruise, but not on an 11-day trip to see a friend.

Comment: Yep. Honestly I didn't notice that at first when reading. Seems the visa guy just made a little brain fart and clearly he meant monthly.

Comment: @alephzero where can I find a round-the-world cruise for 3 months worth of salary?

Comment: @PeterPaff well that rather depends what your salary is, of course, but the point was surely that it's a plausible thing to be *willing* to spend three months salary on.

Comment: @ChrisH That sounds pretty subjective. What if I value spending time with friends over spending time on the open ocean?

Comment: If the person did save up 3 months of salary for an 11 day trip, the bank account behavior and itinerary will be completely different. A real person doing a once-in-a-lifetime trip (i.e. plans to go back home) will have very different looking bank transactions and plans. I wasn't surprised the officer rejected this.

Comment: @PeterPaff lots of things are subjective, and if you have an objective way to determine the legitimacy of stated reasons in visa applications I'm sure lots of governments would love to hear about it. If you value time with friends to the point that you're prepared to spend a quarter of a year's income on an 11 day trip to see a friend, you are an extreme outlier and should not be surprised to find that people are sceptical when hearing that plan, especially when the application appears to have several other issues.

Comment: The whole thing relies on percentages, whether real and written down on based more on feel I do not know. Sure, there are definitely people in the world who earn a relatively small salary, save up, then blow it all on 2 week holidays. There definitely are people who have legitimate extra income outside of their regular salary. But, the percentages show that people getting mysterious extra funds and taking holidays way outside their price range have a high chance of not being legitimate tourists and overstaying.

Comment: @alephzero Without meaning to nitpick, it genuinely isn't obvious to me that this was a typo and not a genuine factor of 12 error. (Unless the officer processing this is Sri Lankan or otherwise very familiar with the local income distribution—then I agree you're almost certainly right.)

Comment: Its the British embassy in Sri Lanka, they will know all about what is normal there. I think the way the numbers add up points very heavily towards it being a honest typing mistake.