# Funds parking during Schengen visa application process

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'll soon be applying for Schengen Visa. I do have funds in the bank to prove the means of subsistence. Do I have to park funds during the time embassy decides whether to grant or refuse the visa?

Comment: Do you mean *do I have to leave the funds in the account untouched between applying and getting a devision*? Or are you asking if it’s necessary to inflate your savings so that the balance looks better? (**No** is the answer to the latter)

Comment: Thank you for dividing both parts. I am clearly seeking an opinion "leaving the funds untouched between applying and getting a decision" part.

Answer (score 14):

**No**. The embassy is looking for evidence that you have a steady income and can afford to travel, not that you have a lump of cash without a clear origin.

"Funds parking", as used in this site, is a bad thing that will likely lead to getting your visa denied: [What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications)

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to extend my question to seek more clarity. I have a bank account in another country where I frequently travel for attending business meetings but do not have a work permit/extension of stay. Can I add the statement of that bank account? How does a VO view such an additional document?

Comment: The embassy is looking for evidence of a stable income, not evidence of wealth. They want to know that you have an incentive to return to your country of origin when your visa expires.

Comment: @Areeb Are there regular transactions between your primary bank account and the one in another country? If so, IMHO you *probably* should include statements for both, so that the ECO can understand the flow of money. If you keep the two accounts completely separate, no need to include. You are not expected to leave the funds in your main account untouched during the application process but when entering Schengen you need to be able to demonstrate that you meet at least the daily minimum requirement, if asked to do so

Comment: @TonyK Stable income is not necessarily an incentive to return to your country of origin, especially if that income doesn't actually require your presence there (e.g. you own a lot of rental properties and pay somebody else to manage them). They want both a strong indication that you'll return to your country of origin at the end of your trip *and* proof that you can afford the trip you're claiming to want to make.