# Standard UK visa rejected due to misinterpretation

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My UK visitor visa was rejected due to misinterpretation from their side. I have 2 bank accounts, one where I receive monthly salary, other from which I transact. I attached both statements - one for proof of monthly income, second for proof of balance of funds. Every quarter or so I transfer the salary into the other account, so they deemed the transfer of money as additional income. The reason for rejection is because they feel I have received 3 times the money in certain months when it’s just the transfer of funds from one account to the other. I have not been given the right to appeal or review. Is there anything I can still do to clarify the confusion?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual text of the rejection letter. You can attach a scan of the letter to your question, using the "Moon and Mountains" button that appears after you push the "Edit" button under your question. Black out or obscure any personal information that appears in the letter (name, address, contact info, et al) before you attach it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: Are you sure the reason was that? IIRC you should write the amount in the official form (so it should not be confusion), also it is not uncommon to have a single bank account for a family, so I'm not sure about your interpretation of their interpretation of your application.

Comment: I'm curious, why would an additional income be a reason for rejection?

Comment: @justhalf The UK visa people really don't like unexplained significant additional income. It could be an attempt to mislead them into thinking the applicant was richer than they actually are. It could be income from some illicit activities, etc.

Comment: @Arno - one thing the UK visa people really don't like is any sign of [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications) - transferring money into one's bank account before applying for a travel visa in the hopes of increasing one's chances of being granted the visa. To note: the term 'funds parking' to describe this practice is almost an exclusively Travel Stack Exchange thing (it, and related visa refusals), been a well-known topic on Travel SE for many years.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are confident that this misinterpretation was the only obstacle to you being granted the visa, you can immediately apply again. This time, add an explanation to your bank statements linking the transfers. This does not avoid having to answers "yes" to "Have you ever been denied a visa?"-questions in the future, but assuming your second attempt is successful, you'd then have corraborating evidence that the denial was just about a minor misunderstanding.