# U.K Visa How to Re-Apply visa which got refused

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for a UK visa and the refusal letter states the reason as below.

> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not
>   satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph V4.2 of Appendix
>   V: Immigration Rules for Visitors because:
>
> You state that you wish to travel to the UK for one week as part of an
>   incentive trip with your company. I acknowledge that you have
>   submitted a letter of employment from your Employer dated 28 Feb 2016
>   that states that they are responsible for all the expenses of the
>   visit. The onus however is on you to qualify for entry clearance based
>   on your own circumstances and your own intentions. Whilst I am
>   satisfied that your employer is willing and able to cover the expenses
>   associated with your visit that is only one aspect of the visitor
>   rules and this does not satisfy me of your own intention to leave the
>   United Kingdom on completion of your visit.
>
> You state that you have 1,500 GBP available for this trip. In support
>   of this you have submitted a bank statement in your name covering a
>   period from 27 July 2015 to 18 February 2016 which shows a final
>   balance of 4.916 OMR (8.95 GBP). I am therefore not satisfied that you
>   have sufficient funds to cover any additional costs whilst in the UK
>   without working or accessing public funds. Your application for a
>   visit is therefore refused under paragraph V4.2 (e).
>
> Given the above I am not satisfied that you have accurately presented
>   your circumstances and therefore your intentions in applying to enter
>   the United Kingdom. This undermines the credibility of your
>   application to the extent that I am not satisfied that you are
>   genuinely seeking entry as a visitor or intend to leave the UK at the
>   end of your visit. Your application is therefore refused under
>   paragrah V 4.2 (a) and (c) of the Immigration Rules.
>
> Future Applications
>
> Any future UK visa applications you make will be considered on their
>   individual merits, however you are likely to be refused unless the
>   circumstances of your application change.
>
> In relation to this decision there is no right of appeal or right to
>   administrative review.

Please find below my doubts and help me for re-applying the Visa.

1) How do I prove my intention to leave the UK on completion of visit.
2) If I Deposit the money 1,500 GBP and take a new statement will that be sufficient.
3) I had actually got a credit of 3,600 GBP via Salary & Bonus on 24Th Feb 2016. As of today I have a balance in my A/C of 400 GBP. Now If I deposit some amount equivalent to 1,500 will be that be enough. Or what as of what date should I take the statement.
4) And for the 3rd Paragraph how to prove the Credibility.

Comment: If you simply deposit the money now, they're going to want to know where the money came from.

Comment: Do not simply deposit £1500 into your account and apply again. This will [guarantee another refusal](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39153/3221), and an even worse one because it may damage your credibility.