# UK visa refused because I failed to provide satisfactory evidence of being a student. What are my options?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I had applied for UK visa recently and it got refused.
My trip was funded by my brother in law and my dad so,
financially it should be no problem.

The reason for refusal were as follows.

> I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V 4.2 of Appendix V: Immigration Rules for Visitors because:
>
> You have sought entry as a visitor for thirty days and have described yourself as a student at Mithibai College, you have stated that you are currently studying Bachelor of Commerce and Chartered accountancy, however you have failed to submit any evidence confirming this. You have failed to submit any evidence of your studies and confirmation of when you will complete this course.
>
> I note that your brother in law is funding this trip however I must be satisfied with your personal circumstances in India. You have submitted no evidence of your studies therefore I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of Appendix V 4.2 (a) of the Immigration Rules.

I am going to reapply.  What was wrong with my previous application?
What do I need to provide in addition to other documents so as to ensure that I get the visa?  What was wrong with my earlier application and what corrective steps should I take for my next application?

Comment: Have you submitted your educational documents? It seems you havent and they think that you want to visit UK and you will never return. You are seen as potential job seeker.

Comment: I think all you need is a university admission letter (properly notarized) stating that you are full time student in your degree program and that you are expected to graduate on ____.

Answer (score 10):

Let us look at V 4.2 of the [Immigration Rules for Visitors](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) in detail:

> **Genuine intention to visit**
>   V 4.2 The applicant must satisfy the decision maker that they are a genuine visitor. This means that the applicant:
>   (a) will leave the UK at the end of their visit; and
>   (b) will not live in the UK for extended periods through frequent or successive visits, or make the UK their main home; and
>   (c) is genuinely seeking entry for a purpose that is permitted by the visitor routes (these are listed in Appendices 3, 4 and 5); and
>   (d) will not undertake any prohibited activities set out in V 4.5 – V 4.10; and
>   (e) must have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to their visit without working or accessing public funds. This includes the cost of the return or onward journey, any costs relating to dependants, and the cost of planned activities such as private medical treatment.

Note that 4.2(a) states: "will leave the UK at the end of their visit". This is in connection with a lack of evidence of your studies.

The entry clearance officer is looking for evidence that you "will leave the UK at the end of your visit". Evidence that you are enrolled at university and will return to your studies would make a strong indication that you are likely to leave the UK and return to India. To resolve this, then, you need only obtain documentation from your university that you are currently enrolled, that you will be enrolled next semester, what you are studying and the expected date of completion of your program. You then include this documentation with your visa application.

While sub paragraph (a) was mentioned in the details, your refusal notice explains that you failed to meet the requirements of Paragraph V 4.2 in its entirety...

> "...I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s)
>   V 4.2..."

This a grave refusal and indicates that there were severe deficiencies in your application.

Because of this, you will want to review everything else in the rules and ensure that you have included all of the other necessary documentation. Some notes for each of these reasons:

- (b): You will not attempt to build up a case for settlement in the UK. If you have travelled to the UK before, and spent significant amounts of time there (e.g. as a student), then they will be aware that you know people in the UK and may have something of a life there. It is even more important in this scenario that you can demonstrate stronger ties to your home country than to the UK.
- (c): Your activities in the UK will be restricted to those listed in Appendix 3 of the visitor rules.
- (d): Ensure that you include nothing in your visa application, nor bring with you to the UK, that might tend to indicate that you will seek employment, academic studies, using the NHS, getting married, etc. Review these sections of the rules to learn what is not allowed on a standard visitor visa.
- (e): That you will not rely upon public funds (i.e., welfare). Pay special attention to [your bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/3221) and your sponsor's financial information as problems with financial documentation are a very common reason for refusals. In addition, [your sponsor **should not** transfer money to your account until after your visa is approved](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39153/3221).

You also should not omit any necessary evidence from your future application that you submitted previously. Such documents need to be resubmitted each time.

Finally, if you do opt to make a fresh application, you are emphatically recommended to study [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) beforehand.

Comment: +1, only to point out that per the first paragraph the 'legal' reason was V 4.2, the entire paragraph, not just (a) which was mentioned as a dot point. In other words, the ECO believed he was not a genuine visitor (a) - (e) complete.

Comment: @GayotFow Right. Everything should be reviewed closely before submitting the new application, which is partly why I quoted 4.2 in its entirety.

Comment: Yeah, it's the whole ball of wax, pretty severe. Good to cite the entire V 4.2  and the last paragraph of your answer, about reviewing, is the best. Nice answer!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe because most of answers / comments were made before some edits but to me this is crystal clear:

> you have stated that you are currently studying Bachelor of Commerce and Chartered accountancy, however you have failed to submit any evidence confirming this. You have failed to submit any evidence of your studies and confirmation of when you will complete this course.

Well then, in your next application don't forget to supply such evidence? What I am unsure about is -- what is your problem? This is absolutely clear in what you missed in your application. Is it a problem of understanding English? Should we translate / expand / explain on this?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! I am going to re apply and this time I am providing my college ID cards and Library cards and also registration letter of Chartered Accountancy course. This should be enough evidence about my studies right? Or should I provide something more!? I am also providing my college results and CA marksheets along with other documents that are mentioned above!