# How to Show Funds if you sponsor someone a UK Visit Visa

Tags: visas, uk, proof-of-funds, proof-provenance-of-funds

I would like to Sponsor a trip to UK as holiday for my parents. My Dad is retired and mom is house wife. I am in Employment (not in UK) have active Bank Account and a Business. Can I attach my Bank Statement & Affidavit stating I am sponsoring my parents Trip? Is that acceptable to show funds this way?
Do I have to transfer the funds to their Account to make it more Legitimate?

Comment: Welcome to travel SE. You might want to check these related questions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking

Comment: cannot find any similar question answered on here. Just edited to be more precise ?

Comment: I believe your question is good, just give it some time till someone comes around to answer you.

Comment: @gayot-fow  I have gone through this https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf. Cannot find anything relevant .

Comment: I know the overall general requirements , just got this question about the Funds however.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick  I can see that's for UK Residents only . What if you not in UK ?

Comment: **DO NOT transfer funds to their account unless they are approved and receive a visa.** If you transfer funds before they apply for the visa, it pretty much [guarantees a refusal](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39153/3221).

Comment: If you cannot find anything relevant in the official guidance or in the canonical linked to above, it means you may be having difficulty reading English text. The guidance has a section devoted to the topic for example.  In this case I would suggest instructing a member of the Law Society to assist your application. You can avoid saddling your parents with a refusal history.