# Undeclared info when reapplying uk visa

Tags: visa-refusals

I am reapplying uk standard visitor visa. Last visa application was refused because of no personal economic ties. I did not declare a bank account because I did not have strong evidence of some large credits. Can I declare that account in my new visa application and explain where that money has come from? How can I explain why I didn't declare that account before?

Comment: Your bank account is not going to make the difference between refusal or acceptance IMHO, i.e. if you have been refused before because of no economic ties, then declaring your bank account will not help. You might want to contact a UK solicitor for crafting an explanation why you did not declare before as that could be tricky and most of all to improve the rest of your application.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is helpful for the OP but not really an answer to this question. I have voted to leave open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a previous refusal wherein you did not disclose relevant information and (presumably) you did not get caught. You want to make a fresh application.

> Can I declare that account in my new visa application and explain
>   where that money has come from?

Yes of course, documenting irregular account flows is part of 'best practices' advice.  Otherwise they will worry if they see unprovenanced funds movement. In the argot of this site, the term 'funds parking' is used to describe how it works...

- [What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications)
- [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)

> How can I explain why I didn't declare that account before?

Good question!  In the last pages of the application form there is a section for free-form text. You can put your explanation there.

Having said that, the very *last* thing you want to do is to enter your explanation as you go along. It should be carefully hammered out beforehand using Notepad or similar composition tool.  This can take a while and might involve several draft copies.   We see a lot of serial refusals that could have been avoided by skillful wordsmithery; it's part of why solicitors can be expensive.

To give you an idea about expectations, it is not uncommon for a good solicitor to spend a *whole afternoon* drafting and then another half-day in peer review and another half-day in partner review.  This is the sort of exculpatory text that ECO's like and can readily accept. One paragraph, two at the very max.

Avoid insipid expressions of remorse or apologies. This goes in to the more generic category of insulting their intelligence, and they do not appreciate it.   If, as you wrote, you were trying to avoid transparency, you can explain it like that.

Another important thing about your explanation: *don't try to double down*, doing that can change a simple thing into a really awkward thing.