# Tier 5 UK visa financial requirement

Tags: visas, uk, working-visas

One of the requirements for a Tier 5 UK visa is to have at least £945 as savings for 3 months in the bank.

Is it acceptable to put that sum in one deposit into the bank account or should it reflect salary savings?

Comment: You may wish to try [expatriates.se] for this question. We don't handle questions about long-term visas. Though you may also wish to see [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39153/3221) for some related information.