# Is money in a bank account mandatory while applying for a Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds

I will be applying for a Schengen visa shortly for my travel in December. In terms of earnings and investments, I can provide evidence of having financial means to support my trip but I don't keep cash in my account.

So I wanted to check whether I should add money to my account just for the visa or is having bank statements showing cash flow, along with salary slips and employer letter sufficient evidence?

Also will credit card statements help?

Comment: Note that a credit card is not proof of funds, since a credit card is effectively a loan (its a debt on you). So you need to provide other evidence of funds (such as a salary statement and proof that its deposited in your account). Also, your account should show that the nature of the trip is not a burden on you. For example, if you are going for 2 weeks and your balance of funds is not sufficient for the minimum amount daily required; then you may be rejected as well.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I make all my spends using credit card to earn points and then duly pay the dues every month. So i believe having a good payment history of credit card should establish credibility. But not sure how embassy will view it.

Comment: The embassy is not looking at your credit history. They are looking at your financial position. It’s not about credibility at all. The simple matter is, you must show that you have access to sufficient funds such that you would not rely on public funds for the duration and nature of your trip.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: I don't think i agree with that as credit card is also a way of funding your expenses.

Comment: Yes but it is not a source of funds. It is a way to pay for your trip. For example, you can pay your flight and hotel via your credit card; but this is not considered a source of funds.

Comment: Ok, so when so funds you are referring to money needed on daily basis while travelling other than stay and flights. I was counting flight+Hotel+daily expense while showing funding evidence. If thats the case then a proof of regular income should work as my trip is months away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I wanted to check whether I should add money to my account just for the visa

No, no, *no*! More below. It's called funds parking. Read this excellent [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/39158/4188) as well.

> Also will credit card statements help?

Yes, if they show a healthy repayment history.

A visa officer typically have an extremely short time at best measured in minutes (and you probably won't need two hands to count the minutes) to decide. S/he will be provided with all the evidence and s/he needs to construct a story of your life and decide whether that story leads to an illegal stay and work in the country you are visiting or a return to your home. Proving you have the funds for the trip is of course crucial because the lack of that will lead to immediate refusal. If you had kept your money in the bank account every month, it'll be easy to see. It's still possible but make sure it can't be construed as a rich uncle borrowing you money for a short period of time.

Beyond that comes the "let's try to divine whether they will return" part and they simply go by experience. People with a steady job (proven by the monthly deposits) and a healthy credit history are very likely to have a steady life they will want to return to. If your monthly income is (far) above the unskilled laborers' then it's very unlikely you could find such a well paying job in the country you are visiting when you are working without the necessary permits. This is what they want to see. Don't ruin it by a sudden deposit.