# How to explain source of funds for UK visa application

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm planning to apply for a 2-week visa to the UK for taking the PLAB 2 test. I have a monthly earning of about £200. I also have savings of £3,000. Out of these, a friend of mine transferred to my account about £2,000 4 months ago. Do I need to explain the source of this money?

Also, can I present evidence of crypto currency earnings from mining investments and also that I purchased gold and silver (precious metal savings) to buttress my financial situation?

Comment: The answer to this question may be of use to you: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab and also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158

Comment: So the majority of your savings are from your friend? Why did the friend transfer the money? Is it a loan to try to help you with your visa application?

Comment: Yes it is a major part. It was refunding of the money I lent. What if I state that it was a loan to try to help me with application, will it be wise?

Comment: If you state it was a loan to help you with the application that will almost guarantee your application fails.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have significant hurdles to overcome: [funds parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications), and that crypto currency is not accepted by virtue of being crypto, nor are gold and silver precious metals as they are not liquid assets (as well as being highly volatile).

Before application, you may wish to look at the guidance offered by @GayotFow in [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Additionally, this site sees a lot of [questions regarding PLAB](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=PLAB), and you could review those for relevancy to you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will not include the gold or cryptos to support application. But how can I deal with the issue of funds parking given that the transfered money was that which my friend returned to me after lending for a year? If I state that it is a loan from my friend, is it tenable?

Comment: Or will submit a 3 to 4 month bank statement of account suffice?

Comment: You should include bank statements to prove that you loaned your friend the money a year ago.

Comment: You seem very willing to say something which is untrue (regarding your funds) in order to pass a test or bureaucratic hurdle. This harms your credibility as a doctor.

Comment: Not like I had intentions of saying it. Just wanted to know the likely response in such a scenario, for future purpose and I may be able to advise others rightly