# How to demonstrate ties to home country for a UK tourist visa?

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, proof-of-ties

I am hoping to get some advice with my application for a tourist visa in the UK.

I applied for a tourist visa last December 2017 and it was rejected because I wasn't able to demonstrate strong ties to my country. Also, I stated on my application that my boyfriend invited me to visit him and indicated that I will be staying with him for 3 months (I just learned how this information might have hurt my application as well). I wasn't able to submit enough documents to prove my relationship with him and that he has enough funds to sponsor my stay in the UK.

I now have all the documents to prove our relationship  amd that he can support me during my stay. My parents will also help in funding the trip and I also have some savings.

My only problem now is how to demonstrate ties to my home country. I don't own a house or any property. My parents own a house and my mom has several properties. Will it help if she indicates that she intends to have me inherit some of those?

I know that getting a job will be the best way to prove ties home but it will take a year or more before I can get a vacation if I apply for a new job. My boyfriend just wants me to experience the culture in his country. And if things go well, we intend to get married afterwards.

Do I have a chance to get my application for a tourist visa approved? Or will we have better chances if we just apply for a spouse visa?

[image]

Comment: I just uploaded the refusal letter. Thank you for responding. Back when I applied for the tourist visa, i didn't have any money in my bank account. It just showed in the history that I got a monthly salary and how i spent it. But now, I have a savings account with money in it and another savings account given by my parents. I am a Filipina. I haven't travelled anywhere outside of the Philippines. I was refering to the spouse visa also known as the UK marriage visa. He was advised that in our case, it will be easier to apply for that visa instead of a tourist visa as I am currently unemployed.

Comment: I’m currently in a similar situation and was wondering what you guys ended up doing?

Answer (score 3):

‘Easier to apply’ may not translate into ‘easy to get’ given the previous refusal. The visa you apply for depends on what your intentions are, not what is easiest to obtain.

- Visit Visa: It’s highly unlikely that showing you have inheritance expectations will help demonstrate home ties. The savings should help, but you’ll need to explain the provenance of the funds in your savings account, otherwise it will appear that you are using a strategy referred to on this forum as ‘funds parking’. [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158) If your parents gave you the money you’ll need to state that and provide evidence eg their bank statements. However, just having savings back home may not be viewed as sufficient to demonstrate a strong intention to leave the U.K. You should also consider reducing the intended length of stay - understandably because of the cost, distance etc you want to spend as much time as possible in the U.K. but a shorter stay is likely to be more credible from the ECO’s point of view. 
  As regards a job, can you look for something with a contracted start date after your intended visit?
- Marriage Visitor Visa: pretty much the same as above plus other requirements https://www.gov.uk/marriage-visa
- Family Visa: To be eligible you and your partner must intend to live together permanently in the UK after you apply. You must be able to prove you are a fiancée and will marry in the UK within 6 months of arriving, and you and your partner must meet the income requirement (currently £18,600pa). You could of course get married in your home country before applying.
  https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/partner-spouse
  A second application so soon after the first rejection risks a further refusal. After considering the available visa options and identifying which applies to your personal situation and intentions, it would probably be worth consulting a qualified immigration lawyer for help with your application.

Comment: The asker might also look for a job as a nurse in the UK. This, if successful, would come with employer sponsorship for a tier 2 skilled worker visa https://www.jobs.nhs.uk/advice/overseas_cand.html

Comment: Thank you so much. My boyfriend and I had considered consulting an immigration lawyer. I just insisted to ask for any advice in this forum in case I can get help on how I can prove my ties to my country without paying a lot of money to a lawyer. I considered looking for a nursing job but mostly are in England and there are some in Wales and no available nursing jobs for a foreigner in Scotland, where he lives, so we consider that as our last option. Thank you once again for responding to my inquiry.