# My parents UK visitor visa is refused for inconsistent transaction

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am a UK permanent resident and I am sponsoring my parents visa and it was refused twice.

This refusal says that their account statement doesn't match with the income.

My father is a farmer in India and he also does some side business as a contractor supplying manpower to local construction companies.

What should I do next to get this approved? What kind of documents will help?

I am fully sponsoring his trip and I had provided following documents:

His and my mother's bank account statement for a year.
Net worth certificate for both parents. ITR for the last 3 years. Confirmed return tickets. My account statements and salary slip.
Invitation letter and salary slip and account statement from UK. My sister's (in India) letter stating that she would take care of the affairs in India.

Cover letter from my parents explaining the purpose of visit.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)

Comment: It's more than money. The Refusal Notice bullet points 3 and 4 address inconsistencies in the source and proof of legitimacy of your and your parent's income, while bullet point 5 brings up an entire new subject: your parents' lack of home ties to India. You say (or said) that your sister would help take care of your parent's business while they traveled, while the officer heard your father say that he would have no dependents remaining in India, while his son and daughter-in-law live in the UK...

Comment: ...This is a textbook example of weak home ties; you can read more about this issue [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113916/how-to-demonstrate-ties-to-home-country-for-a-uk-tourist-visa). Weak home tires itself is enough to scupper a visa application, as the traveler(s) would be seen as highly likely to overstay a visa and remain with the family in the UK.

Comment: I think ECO completely disregarded the tax returns of the last 3 years, and farm and home ownership were certified by a chartered account in a net worth certificate.

Comment: My sister provided an undertaking to care for family farms, and she also provided a letter from her hospital confirming her employment and income, demonstrating her financial independence. This explains why my parents mentioned having no dependents in India. The application question was confusing, so they answered no dependents but clearly mentioned in the cover letter that they have family in India and provided a letter of support from their daughter. Her employment letter verified her income, demonstrating familial support. This was not taken in account by ECO.