# my Short term visa 11 months has been refused

Tags: visa-refusals

[image]

my Short term visa 11 months refused , to study English and I have 2 nationalities Egyptian and Syrian but I came from Syria in 2001 so I wanted to know is that becuase of the Syrian nationality  or only for finance matter and  shall I write letter for reason to study English ? And also I work freelancer 
And in the letter I don’t understand what do they mean by ( your immigration history )

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE!  Since this is about student visas rather than travel, the question would be better suited for [Expatriates StackExchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).  However, it looks like [this Q&A on bank statements & UK visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) might be helpful to you.  Also, "your immigration history" means places you have travelled and visas you have applied for in the past, particularly if you have been refused a UK visa previously.

Comment: They will never accept that you receive salary by Western Union. They expect you to receive your salary like most people, with pay slips and also it should show on a bank statement. It looks like you work on contract and receive payment for your services by money transfer. That will be a big problem with getting a UK Visa. UK Visa officials want to be able to trace clearly the source of your income, so preferably it should be a bank statement showing salary deposits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)

Comment: You were refused solely for financial reasons, as you did not demonstrate the source of funds in your bank accounts. This is what the letter says. It has nothing to do with your nationality.

Comment: There are many issues with your application. How are you going to get additional funds to pay the rest of your fees and to maintain yourself in the UK? The guidance for short term students says students must _maintain and accommodate themselves out of funds available to them  & meet the cost of their onward or return journey_.

Comment: According to the rules, [you are not supposed to work](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/722982/Short-term-students-guidance-v8.0-EXT.PDF) . `Applicants must not: intend to take employment (other than as an elective which meets paragraph
A57D(a)(iii) of the rules), including:
o paid or unpaid work
o a work placement
o work experience in the UK
• intend to be:
o self-employed
o involved in business activities or any professional activity in the UK`

Answer (score 1):

The officer made a typographical mistake when writing your refusal letter.  The words "Do not include reference to additional information if refusing on mandatory suitability ground(s) only" were an instruction to the officer that he or she should have been deleted.  Now, I think the answer to your question is obvious: the letter should have said

> In deciding... I have considered:
>
> - your application and any additional relevant information you have provided with it
> - your immigration history

It's just saying that they considered your application form, the documents you provided, and your immigration history (e.g., what visas you've had in the past and whether you kept the terms of those visas).

Comment: Methinks you are further going to confuse the OP with this answer. Clearly English is not their native language and when you write that the officer made a mistake, they will think you are supporting their application and that the refusal was unfair.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen I edited my answer to say "made a mistake when editing your refusal letter" at about the same time as you posted your comment. Do you think that's clearer?

Comment: I don't really know. Their comprehension of English is not the best and you risk them latching on _the officer made a mistake_ part.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen OK. I see your point but I don't see how else to answer the question. I've made the answer as clear as I can. If the asker misunderstands that, there's nothing more I can do.