# Uk visit visa refusal by V4.2 a and c

Tags: uk

[image][image]
What to do now i am not clear what he want to know about me
My consultant ask me to submit this case again nd we will show how our money link to my business

Comment: Hi. We already have a question about this, which covers your case. Please read the answer there. If there is something not covered there, please edit the question to what specific part you need help with.

Comment: Most of those **consultants** are just scammers.

Comment: @HonoraryWorldCitizen      So what to do now?

Comment: Spend the next one month reading about UK visas here. You will become more knowledgeable than any consultant. After that you can reapply by submitting a polished application. Use the search function here to find highly rated answers on UK visas. Start with this https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking