# What documents to substitute bank statement as proof of salary received?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, filipino-citizens

[image]

Hi everyone.
I want to ask help and advise. My sister got her refusal notice, picture uploaded. She is from Philippines.

My sister is employed and they paid her cash. She submitted her certificate of employment, 6 months payslip and approved leave of absence from her company.  And not having bank account statement is the main ground for refusal, I believe it is, as they mentioned in the 3rd paragraph.
We are planning to reapply this month as we want her to come mid of April to join us in our special event.
My sister provided evidence of family ties. Her partner for 16 years, family and work are her ties and reasons to return to Philippines.

Questions:

(1) Do you think submitting Certificate of Annual Compensation received for the year 2018 or  Philippine BIR FORM 2316, Certificate of Salary Received for January and February 2019 or the last 6 months, certifying as well that it is cash payment, attached her cash voucher and payslip from her company would be sufficient proof of her income/salary received in lieu of bank account statement?

I found out today that she has savings account in a Rural Bank since 2011 up to now.. there were transactions made, deposits and widrawals, but nothing left there as the moment as she withdraw the last money last month,  could we use it as additional document? Picture uploaded

(2) Can we satistfy and prove to the ECO that my sister is a genuine visitor to the UK by providing again the letter from her partner, stating their relationship history and future plans together, their photos, our family photos, Identification cards of her family in Philippines, and will add letter from father of her partner certifying my sister and her partner live in his property, their relationship, and submit proof of residence under his name like utility bills?

(3) Is the chance of reapplying and submitting additional documents mentioned above would give us higher chance of successful visa application?

THANK YOU in advance.
All advises will be appreciated.
[image][image]

Comment: `And not having bank account statement is the main ground for refusal,` Unfortunately the British are not only interested in whether an applicant will leave the UK after their visit. They also particularly care about money laundering which is why so many people get refused under [provenance of funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158). Without bank statements her chances are very very slim.

Comment: Some credibility can be added by having your sister include her tax returns, as a cash economy person (and there's nothing illegal about a cash business) can show she's following the rules by paying taxes (as any person who receives income must). You might review this SE:Travel page as well: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131863/uk-visit-visa-how-do-we-prove-self-employment

Comment: Thanks David... my sister earns minimum wage which exempts her from tax, I ask her to secure TAX exemption certificate so we can submit it as well.