# UK visitor visa refused on V4.2 (a) V4.2 (c) even though sponsor would pay for the entire trip!

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My father & mother in laws, recently applied for a family visit visa to come and take part at my son’s birthday and spend sometime with our family.
I sponsored their entire trip and showed evidence of funds available in my savings account. I provided my payslips & bank statements of 8 months. Also for accommodation I provided UK land registration documents + house inspection. But in the refusal letter they say “some of the cost” which is not true. I gave a complete breakdown of how much a 24 days trip will cost and I submitted my savings account which had 3x more funds available.
The applicants who are both retained elderly, provided their property assets and rental income documents. Their main source of income in Bangladesh is generated from the rents. For a 24 days trip, their were sufficient funds available from both sides. 
However, we are now aware that the applicants bank statement did not show enough regular transaction, although fund balance were good. This was picked up by ECO and used it to refuse. Since there are no opportunity to appeal, we can’t explain the fact that the applicants are both elderly and don’t always use the bank to put the money in and out. My father in law is old fashioned and prefers to deal with everything in cash. In fact cash is still widely used in Bangladesh economy. 
We want to reapply but would like to get it right next time around, any advice will be greatly appreciated?[image]
Also they say, because they haven’t traveled to anywhere else before, then apparently they will not leave the UK!
But...they are both in their late 60’s. That generation of Bangladeshis rearly has the opportunity to go abroad, they only want to come to the UK due to family, their daughter, me and the grandchildren. We go to Bangladesh to visit them, and the kids just wanted to have them over for few weeks to return the favour.

Comment: Ali, welcome back. Please read the question linked above, which should give you an answer to this question.

Comment: @Ali Akbar Submitting tax returns proving rental income might help if they re-apply

Comment: I don't know why it isn't linked above, but you should also read [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39153/3221) which explains exactly this refusal and how UK authorities view such deposits.