# How to explain allowance received without any document from employer?

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, philippines, ukrainian-citizens

We are reapplying for UK standard visitor visa for my sister.
The refusal ground was about the proof of salary received.
This time we are providing BIR 2316 Certification of Compensation Payment /Tax Withheld from the company, but in that form they only stated the basic salary and the 13th month bonus my sister received. They didnt include the allowance of Php 1500 my sister received at the end of every month in the said certificate. They didnt also want to give copy of the voucher for this allowance. And it was not also included/does not appear in her payslips.

The problem now is we stated the basic salary + allowance in the online application form we submitted. We are worried now that this will be another ground for refusal-  proof of allowance received. We dont know how to explain it in the cover letter.. since the company doesnt want to give proof or even a letter explaining about it.

They only gave us certificate of employment (COE) stating daily rate, start date of my sister employment to present, her position in the company, and approved Leave of Absence. (LOA)

We are submitting my sister savings account bank statement from december 2018 to present date... together with LOA, COE, payslips and the BIR 2316 ANNUAL Compensation Payment to answer the refusal ground.

Any advice how to explain the allowance in the cover letter?
Her visa appointment is on March 4.

Any advice is appreciated.
Thank you 
[image][image]

This is our concern, we mentioned it in the online application form, there's question about income earn each month after tax.
We want to further clarify it in the cover letter  but we dont know how to explain it well, and not be another reason for refusal.

Comment: The company is giving your sister money, but no documents to prove it? The UK authorities will find this very strange and look at it negatively, as you have already discovered.

Comment: Sad to say yes... they give (meal) allowance every month, they let them sign a voucher but they dont give copy of it. We ask and even prepare a certificate of salary received including allowance and bonus, but they refused to sign on it.

Comment: They said they gave my sister a copy of the voucher but until now they didnt, that's the reason my sister declared the allowance in the online form, and now there's no way to edit the form as it is already submitted online.

Comment: Your explanation seems convoluted to me and an EXO only has about four minutes to make a decision. You may want to get an immigration attorney to craft the cover letter for the next application. As it stands you’re looking at a second successive refusal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.... We will expect and accept another refusal since no chance to edit the application form or refund the visa fee, no chance and time to convince the employer to give us document to show allowance received. Thanks again

Comment: @MsPisces If the application cannot be improved and you accept that a new application will again be refused, then why file it? Repeated refusals, particularly in quick succession, will make a future application's success even more unlikely.

Comment: Hi David. There's development as of this time, finally the admin gave a copy of voucher but only August 2018-January 2019. In the voucher, allowance is included