# 6 months salary vouchers, latest month not included

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, philippines

The employer provided us just today 6months salary vouchers as proof of salary and allowance received, but they didnt give my sister the latest month - February 2019 (for the reason it is not available due to printer is broken.)
They gave August 2018 to January 2019.

She is reapplying this March 4.
Refusal ground was about proof of salary received.
She is submitting now the 6 months salary vouchers, BIR 2316 Annual Compensation Payment/Tax Withheld, Certificate of Employment  and Approved Leave of Absence, and her personal savings account bank statement Dec 2018 to present.

1.Do you think without February salary voucher will affect our second application to Standard Visitor Visa?

2. Do we need to explain in the cover letter why we dont have February voucher? (We are not so sure of the reason, why they didnt give copy)

We are sponsoring her trip to UK. We provided all necessary documents, and there was no question about it. Her ground for refusal is her proof of salary received.[image]

Comment: Just an opinion but for an early March application I don’t think it should be critical not to have proof of February’s voucher payment given that you have 6 months’ worth, providing ALL other aspects of the application are in order. Your previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133074/how-to-explain-allowance-received-without-any-document-from-employer has indicated that the cash voucher payment is relatively small.

Comment: Thanks @Traveller. The voucher shows salary and allowance my sister received every month.

Comment: Thanks @ThE iLlEgAl aLiEn.. and yup nobody knows. Less worried now for we can prove the stated allowance through the salary and allowance voucher.

Answer (score 1):

The general policy is the cutoff date of the bank statements should be within three months of application/adjudication.

In this instance you are fine because your latest financial document is within the three month window.

As for how the will evaluate the overall application, nobody knows.

Reference

[image]

Noteworthy is that the **only** reason for denying this application was the **expired** financial document.

Comment: Thanks again...maybe it is also best to explain in the cover letter why we dont have february salary and allowance voucher. Thanks for this information.