# British army assessment visa

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, nigerian-citizens

I’m a Nigerian , I have been invited by the British army for an assessment next month , my dad is willing to sponsor my Traveling expenses and my brother who is in the British army and a citizen of United Kingdom is will accommodate me, I am unemployed currently do my apprenticeship in my fathers company ,my dad has paid N1,500,000 (£3000) into my account with a letter that represents that ,my father is a business man and I have paperwork to back that up  , I have also added my father assets in Nigeria  to my visa application..do I need to bring my fathers company bank ste together with my own..or should I just bring only mine since he has already sent the money to my account???

Comment: Transferring money before obtaining the visa makes it [much more likely that your visa will be refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/39153/3221).  But you needed to include your father's information anyway, if he is paying for your trip. It is even more important that you include as much detail as you can now.

Comment: What details should I include???