# How do I show that I just got new job and have a personal business as well

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, paperwork, applications

My UK visa has been refused recently.

Fast forward and I have been employed under a government initiative. Before the application I was with a family business and after the refusal the government agency called me to start work. The assumption later states 6th June 2019 and I have started working in July.

I also just registered my event company as a part time job or for extra income.

The previous application shows at the time I was with the family business.

Which documents should I submit when I reapply for a standard visitor visa?

Secondly, how does one show that the funds indicated in the application are available and exclusively to you for the purpose of your travel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Which documents to submit when I reapply for a standard visitor visa?

The same as before - employment contract for your new role plus payslips. If you re-apply immediately you’ll need to provide this for both old and new jobs (covering at least 6 months), however a rapid re-application, even with a new job, is likely to result in another refusal. I would recommend that you wait at least 3 months before re-applying.

2 How does one show that funds are available to you and exclusively for the purpose of travel?

The gold standard is to have the funds in an account in your own name, and to be able to show that you’ve accumulated them from your own income. If you have to use a sponsor, they need to provide full evidence of the source of the money (bank statements, employment contract/payslips, tax return etc). Do not be tempted to have a sponsor deposit money in your account upfront (see [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking/39158#39158)

Comment: Well noted. My new date for assessment will be in November . My income wont be enough for the trip even if I save. In our part of the world (Africa) plane tickets are expensive

Comment: Also I have a registered company

Comment: @Kay jay Having a registered company probably won’t carry much weight unless a) you can show it’s been trading profitably for at least 6 months; b) you can prove you draw an income from it, if you do; and c) your personal bank statements and tax returns corroborate that.