# Is this considered ‘funds parking’ / UK visa bank statement

Tags: visas, uk, proof-provenance-of-funds

I will be doing a short term student visa on my American passport and I have a small problem. My father has a savings bank account. He stores all the money required for my education inside it.The last time he did an activity in this bank account was like more than a year ago. He has 18,000 USD in this bank account but recently he placed 3,000 USD . So are the 3,000USD considered ‘ funds parking ‘ 
 They are not from his income. He is unemployed but has lots of properties so he sold a land and deposited the money . I also have a question , how recent should the bank statement be?

Answer (score 2):

Q1 Is a deposit into a bank account that hasn’t been used for more than a year ‘funds parking’?

Typically no, it’s not ‘funds parking’ if the source of the (unusual) deposit can be proved and the deposit is not of a temporary nature to artificially boost the account balance prior to a visa application. [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)

Q2 How recent should the bank statement be?

The rule of thumb is statements covering a period of six months and the six month period should end with the most recent statement prior to submitting the application. Ideally, the most recent statement should be dated within one month before the application [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)