# How do I answer visa questions about my salary?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds, ghanaian-citizens

I have seen refusals stating the amount you stated is 3x,4x your disposable income.

My mum-in-law would be responsible for my accommodation and maintenance in the UK. Does it mean she would be paying financially towards my visit?

When they ask "How much do you earn each month after-tax," I am a salaried worker with £250.00 income monthly and also an Entrepreneur with annual income of £1500.00. Should I combine the two incomes?

When they ask "What is your employment status," can i choose Employed, and Self employed at the same time?

Edit: My business is registered with a guarantee income, my primary occupation is IT technician. I was refused family visit visa based on the amount stated as the cost of my travel is six times my disposable income. I am a Ghanaian.

Comment: 1. In effect yes - otherwise you’d have to pay for lodgings and food yourself, and thus the intended cost of the trip to you personally would be higher. 2. I’d put the entrepreneur income under the subsequent ‘other income’ category, assuming it’s not guaranteed income. 3. No, choose the category that best describes your primary occupation. You can explain further if you need to in the ‘Additional Information’ section at the end of the application.

Comment: this needs more details still. Did you get a refusal or have you just heard that others got refusals? What is your citizenship? How long do you plan to visit for? What ties do you have to your home country?

Comment: @Traveller come on, you shouldn't answer in comments, right?

Comment: @Kate Gregory Agreed, however it seemed to me there is more behind the question than the OP has disclosed. Happy to post as an answer, just didn’t think it would be enough

Comment: @Traveller my business is registered with a guarantee income, my primary occupation is IT technician. I was refused family visit visa based on the amount stated as the cost of my travel is six times my disposable income. Also how much do you think i should state for the cost  my mun inlaw would be paying? My visit was 14 days. Am a Ghanaian

Comment: @Mensah Akwasi No-one can tell you what the cost to your mother-in-law should be, that’s up to you to decide along with her. Unfortunately, by UK standards your income is very low, so affordability and proportionality to your income is always going to be problematic, even with a sponsor. With one refusal already you’ll need to put in a watertight application to stand any chance of success.

Comment: Honestly, unless you have other very strong ties to your home country, or you have a sponsor with a lot of money you can rely on, you can forget about getting a visitor visa. Your total income is less than the cost of living in the UK. Any trip to the UK would represent many many many months of your disposable income. You would just be seen as someone trying to enter the UK who would never leave.

Comment: @Traveller worth posting as an answer now?

Answer (score 2):

You are a Ghanaian citizen applying for a UK Standard Visitor Visa. The first thing you should do is have a read on the relevant questions on this site regarding proof of funds, and proof of provenance of funds:

- [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)
- [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e)
- [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)

Now, to answer your specific questions:

> My mum-in-law would be responsible for my accommodation and maintenance in the UK. Does it mean she would be paying financially towards my visit?

Yes. You mother-in-law will be sponsoring part of your trip, including vital expenses for lodging and food. Therefore she is supporting you financially and you should state this in your application.

> When they ask "How much do you earn each month after-tax," I am a salaried worker with £250.00 income monthly and also an Entrepreneur with annual income of £1500.00. Should I combine the two incomes?

You should declare, explain, and support both incomes. There is an "other income" field you can use in the application to describe your entrepreneur income.

> When they ask "What is your employment status," can i choose Employed, and Self employed at the same time?

You should choose the category that best describes your primary occupation. Most probably you are stably employed, and have some revenues coming from your self-employed status. In general, you can use the "Additional Information" section of the application to add all the details you deem necessary to support your application.