# Sponsoring wife but not applying with her

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

We are Indian citizens, can I sponson my wife and children for uk visit visa as I am not applying with them. Or transfer money to her account and apply.

Comment: Yes, of course you can sponsor your family, https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf#page25 What makes you think you can’t?

Comment: Be aware that if you add funds to your family's account(s) so they can afford the trip, UKVI will want to know the provenance of those funds — that the funds are legally-acquired post-tax monies available to the family with no expectation of repayment on your part. Read [this question and answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking), as well as the linked pages, for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely normal for someone to pay for the travel of a spouse and not travel with them. It happens all the time.

The way to do this is for her, on the application, to state that you will be paying for all costs of the trip. Then you submit financial statements for both you. Hers will be minimal, but you should submit details of your finances to prove not only that you have the money, but that you in a good enough financial position that the trip being planned makes sense.

It is best not to transfer money to her account. You would need to explain the transfer, and that would probably involve you sharing your financial details anyway.