# UK visa application form questions

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, nigerian-citizens

I’m 22 and I’m applying for a tourist visa from Nigeria. My father is my sponsor. He is paying for everything.

I have some questions concerning the form.

What does the section that says “ How much money are you personally planning to spend on your visit to the UK?” imply? Does it mean that’s the money accessible to you?

If my sponsor is paying for everything should the “How much money will they be paying towards your visit” section and “How much money are you personally planning to spend on your visit to the UK?“ second section have the same amount?

Please I’m really confused. Help

Comment: Yes, put the same figure in both sections of the application (I have done it this way twice). However if your profile is ‘22, no savings, no strong ties to Nigeria, no/little previous travel history’ your application will be refused IMHO.

Comment: @Traveller

Did you specify that your sponsor was covering everything?

Comment: Yes. In fact, I *was* the sponsor. As a citizen/resident of the destination country, I was also the applicant’s host for the trip.

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully sponsored a UK visitor visa application three times since 2017, all for the same applicant. The latest one (in 2023) was for a long-term multiple entry visitor visa. On each occasion I was paying all the costs.

The question about how much are you planning to spend is asking about the *total planned cost of the trip*. The second question is asking about *how much your sponsor is contributing* towards those costs.

As your sponsor is paying for everything, put the same amount in both sections of the application. You will need to demonstrate that your sponsor is willing and financially capable of providing the promised financial support by including his bank statements and evidence of income eg payslips plus a letter confirming his intention. The ECO needs to be convinced that the funds will be *available* to you when the time comes.

See also [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) and [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)

Comment: I have 2 questions please. 1. If you put say a smaller amount in the The question about how much are you planning to spend, would you be required to prove that you have the amount with your own personal savings or bank statement? 
2. If you put the same amount in the  question about how much are you planning to spend and the second question asking about how much your sponsor is contributing towards those cost, would your own bank statement be required?

Comment: @Venna Yes to both questions. Applicants should always provide their own bank statements, for the reasons explained in the linked question. The exception would be if you do not have a bank account, but that would very likely be a red flag and you’d need to give a credible reason why not. Remember also that if you have applied before, the information you give in subsequent applications must be *consistent* with previous applications. Eg don’t try to claim now that you don’t have a bank account if you’ve previously said you do.